# Windows Server 2008 permission manager?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008

I run an external web server for my company, its a Windows 2008 VPS and its always causing me a headache, usually with permissions.

I have one account created in Plesk, with a few subdomains. Things get uploaded/updated on a daily basis, and every now and then (especially with new builds) the permissions die. Is there a program that can manage all the permissions automatically so I don't have to do them manually every time it falls over? I've had a bit of a google, but nothing ideal has popped up. Wondering if theres anyone who recommends something before I dive into installing software on a live server.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions relating to software development. Because this question deals with the configuration of servers in a business environment, it's probably better suited to Super User.

Comment: ah great, not heard of that site. Is there a way the question can be migrated?

Comment: Click flag and then choose the "other" radio button. In the text field explain that you'd like the question migrated to ServerFault. My apoligies for steering you wrong if you saw the earlier version of this comment, it seems the user interface is different when flagging your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear about why "the permissions die".
One simple way to set file and folder permissions is to use the `cacls` or `icacls` commands (standard Windows commands, included with every Windows). You have to write a script to run this command with the desired parameters.

You can either use a scheduled task to run your script each hour/day/whatever, or use another method to trigger the script at the right time (for example after each new build).

Another utilities can be SetACL (opensource).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Sorry yes.... was a bit loose on the specifics. Say if i had an IUSR_X account that needs full permission, sometimes it just removes itself from the permissions list, so you have to manually add it back in.

Answer (score 1):

`icacls` is the way to go.  As @Gregory_MOUSSAT said, it's already in Windows path by default. Point it to the folder root in question and save current permissions to a file (assuming they are currently the way you want them).

`icacls c:\inetpub\wwwroot\* /save c:\myperms.txt /T`

Then when they get messed up, reapply:

`icacls c:\windows\wwwroot\ /restore c:\myperms.txt`